# Artillery Simulation

Tags: java, physics, libgdx

I need some help on a simulation of an Artillery like this one

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YktWSKo_UbA.

I cant figure out how to make the "tomato" to get to the selected spot.

Where can I get solutions for this kind of questions in the future? Physics programming books? I am using LibGDX (Java).

Answer (score 0):

I bought '[Physics for Game Developers](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920012221.do)' and I liked it. It even has an 'Artillery'-example in it. One with canons.

As far as I remember it was in C but you can easily rewrite it into Java.

If you do not want to buy books. You can ask questions here on Stack Exchange or you can look into [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your link at work, but an artillery trajectory is mostly subject to gravity.

Horizontal speed `vh` is assumed to be constant while in air and the initial location is `x0`:

```
x(t) = vh . t + x0
```

Vertical coordinate accelerate with gravity `g`, so the second derivative is `-g`:

```
y"(t) = -g
```

You know the initial vertical speed `vv`, so you can set the constant after integrating:

```
y'(t) = -g . t + vv
```

You add the initial location (`y0`) after integrating again:

```
y(t) = -0.5 . g^2 t + vv . t + y0
```

Now you have `x` and `y`, the horizontal and vertical coordinates in function of the time `t`. `g` is roughly 9.81, it is the constant for the gravitation formula